# Can we hide a constant hashed key used for AES encryption of a password?

Tags: encryption, aes, java

Are there any methods in java to hide a constant hashed key which is embedded in a class?
FYI, the key is used to AES encrypt a password used to authenticate a Web Service which would only take a plain text.

Comment: This is not possible for software generally, but Java is particularly unsuitable for hiding implementation details

Comment: Thanks, I corrected. By the way, I had to use a constant just to avoid redundancy of entering the password every time I restart my application.

Comment: If java is unsuitable what other language does and how?

Comment: No other language, which was what I meant by the first part of my comment.  It's just that Java is particularly bad, because it's only compiled to machine code at runtime, and so is stored in a highly human readable format.

Comment: Um, my Java is compiled to byte code at compile time.  (The byte code includes string constants, but then, so does machine code.)

Comment: @BobBrown Yes, that is true.  In the interest of brevity, I over-simplified and left out an important step.  It does compile to bytecode, which is what is stored.  This is not directly easily human-readable as I implied, but can be decompiled into source that is far more readable than decompiled machine code, because far, far more metadata is stored with byte code than with assembly.   The resultant source will be much more readable.

Comment: Please note that changing your question after there have been answers is frowned upon. This tends to invalidate answers that may be perfectly valid for the original question.  The preferred approach is to ask new questions..

Comment: @Xander and OP: remember Java mapping between String/chars and bytes is nontrivial and if you're not careful inconsistent, which is disastrous for crypto. Anything called a 'key' *or* 'salt' in JCA should be `byte[]`, only something called 'password' should be `char[]` or `String`. This gives you a little free obfuscation because a constant `byte[]` (or any array) compiles to a series of element stores, not the obvious literal used for `String`. This is slightly harder to read, but not much.

Comment: @atk from the data I see (and I hate getting precise times only when they're old enough to be useless!) the single edit was before all answers and all comments but maybe one and that one isn't invalidated.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, the edit was after my answer,  and made the answer as written rather incomplete,  though not entirely invalidated.  Nonetheless, it's a good practice to avoid changing questions after there are answers,  especially since SO doesn'offer any alert whatsoever that the question has been changed

Answer (score 1):

No. If you embed something in source code, it is available to anyone with the source code.

Under most circumstances, you want each system to have its own keys, so that two users of your software cannot attack each other. In a hosted environment, you want separation of duties between dev an operations - dev should not have the keys that operations uses to protect data, since dev's job description is to write the code not be custodians for the data.

Rarely, you will want to embed your public key to ensure that your software can communicate with your server. This is a little more flexible without hard coding it, and easier to change if not hard coded.

<strike>All that said, if you want ask a different question that talks about the problem you are trying to solve instead of just how you are trying to solve it, we can probably give you some better advice.</strike>

Since you have changed your question and have added that you are trying to send a password to a web service, I have the following advice: don't do it that way. You are inventing your own crypto protocol to authenticate, and you are planning to only protect the password. If you can use TLS, use that. If you are using SOAP, you can use WS-Security. Your custom protocol doesn't protect against password replay (I don't need the cleartext password, just the encrypted password that someone else sent), doesn't protect other messages sent to the server, and is decryptable by anyone with a copy o f your client software. And don't try to fix your protocol - there are gads of books written about how subtle flaws can destroy the security of a network protocol, and if you try to fix yours, you'll only wind up reinventing TLS (if you're lucky)

Comment: Well, the web service I consume is an external client, they designed it that way, and I can't blame them because my corporation itself has a major flaw where it embedded a key which is used to encrypt a database password, so that way anyone who has access to app servers and source code can get a production database's password. Anyway as per the answers, I would now or never embed keys in such a fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth thinking about what you are trying to do, rather than how to achieve it.

1. You have a distributed client that uses a web service.
2. The web service restricts use via a password.

So the question is how can you distribute a version of the client while protecting the password that it needs to access the web service?

If you control the installation process and are using Windows you could store the password in the context of a service account, and use DPAPI to gain access to it.

If you control the web service, you could front end it with another service that required digital certificates or unique passwords and issue one with each client.

You may also be able to restrict access to the web service with an IP address whitelist.

What you can't do, though, is stop someone getting a secret out of code that you distribute to them, however hard you try.